# How to add scrollbars to my HTML that disappear if the content is smaller than the limit

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a form that has an expandable widget. The problem is that when the widget is open, The form extends outside the limit in the content box, and it looks bad.

I tried using `overflow:scroll` but it creates 2 ugly scrollbars that do not disappear even if the content is smaller then the content box. I only need one vertical scrollbar.

Visual Studio also alerted that overflow-y is not available in CSS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your overflow to `auto` and define the height and/or width of the element.

Answer (score 2):

`overflow-x` and `overflow-y` are part of the CSS3 proposal, and work in all of the current versions of the big four browsers.

I usually do:

```
overflow: auto;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
```

The reason is that sometimes browsers treat `overflow: auto` as `overflow: scroll` (two ugly scrollbars) as soon as content overflows in one direction, but those browsers already support `overflow-x` and `overflow-y`, which get precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Swilliams gave a good answer about how to treat the symptom. But, you might want to think about the root cause too - if the content box were not constrained to a fixed size, it could shrink and/or expand to fit any size form, without scroll bars. Web pages are flexible by design, and attempts to "fix" that flexibility usually end up running into problems of this sort.

Comment: There are many situations where this is appropriate, though. Take, for example, a PRE block with code.

Comment: Yes, definitely. That's why I didn't phrase my answer in absolutes, saying things like "you might want to think about" and "usually end up running into problems" instead.